# Multi-Provider invalid member on null: 'collection' on provider construct

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The error received:

```
NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'collection'
```

I'm using the [Flutter Provider Package 4.3.2+2](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) for complex state management.

I get my data from Firebase, this is the data structure:
[image: data structure]

This is the provider class:

```
class ClientsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  FirebaseFirestore _fs;
  StreamSubscription<QuerySnapshot> _stream;
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> clients = [];
  ClientsProvider() {
    _stream = _fs.collection("clients").snapshots().listen((event) {//THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR POINTS 
      clients = event.docs;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _stream.cancel();
  }
}
```

This is the parent widget:

```
class _ParentState extends State<Parent> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            Provider<ClientsProvider>(
                create: (context) => ClientsProvider()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider<MyProvider>(
                create: (context) => MyProvider()),
          ],
          child: Dashboard(),//This widget contains the Child() widget two widgets down. 
        );
  }
}
```

This is the child widget that needs to be updated when the firebase snapshot updates:

```
class _ChildState extends State<Child> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildAddNew(),
        Consumer<ClientsProvider>(
          builder: (context, clientProvider, child) {
            return Container(child: Text(clientProvider.clients.toString()));
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Once again, the error received:

```
NoSuchMethodError: invalid member on null: 'collection'
```

The data isn't null, why am I receiving this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_fs` is null because you never assigned it.  Perhaps you meant to do this, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/):

```
FirebaseFirestore _fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
```